# Remover Primeiro Nome e Último Nome de um Nome Completo

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, concatenação-de-string

Estou usando o comando SUBSTRING_INDEX para pegar o primeiro nome e o último nome de um campo da tabela "Nomes".

```sql
SELECT
SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', 1) AS primeiro_nome,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', -1) AS ultimo_sobrenome
FROM `nomes`
```

Só que preciso colocar todos os outros sobrenomes no campo "nomes_do_meio".
Ex: João Pedro da Silva Souza Queiroz
primeiro_nome = "João"
ultimo_nome = "Queiroz"
nomes_do_meio = "Pedro da Silva Souza"

Se alguém souber fazer isso no SQL eu agradeço (pois no PHP é mais fácil hehe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo assim:

```
select 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', 1) as primeiro_nome,
SUBSTRING(nome_completo,LOCATE(' ',nome_completo) + 1,char_length(nome_completo) - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(nome_completo)) - LOCATE(' ',nome_completo)) as nomes_do_meio,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', -1) as ultimo_sobrenome,
nome_completo 
from nomes;
```

O nome João Pedro da Silva Souza Queiroz tem 33 caracteres *char_length(nome_completo)*, o primeiro espaço aparece na posição 5 *LOCATE(' ',nome_completo)*, o último espaço na posição 8 contanto de trás para frente *LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(nome_completo))*. Para pegar apenas os caracteres entre o primeiro e o último espeço, basta pegar a partir da primeira vez que aparece o espaço(posição 5) e somar mais um, para ficar na posição 6 *LOCATE(' ',nome_completo) + 1*, depois pegar somente o total de caracteres sem a contar com a primeira e a última vez que aparece o espaço em branco *LOCATE(' ',nome_completo) + 1,char_length(nome_completo) - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(nome_completo)) - LOCATE(' ',nome_completo)*

```
João Pedro da Silva Souza Queiroz
123456789012345678901234567890123
321098765432109876543210987654321
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo aqui e gostei da explicação!

Comment: Ótimo. Sobre a solução proposta pelo @wees-smith, poderia fazer assim: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', 1) AS primeiro_nome, TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(nome_completo,SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', 1),''),SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', -1),'')) AS nomes_do_meio, SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', -1) AS ultimo_sobrenome FROM nomes; Também vai funcionar. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que não seja a forma adequada, porém funcional:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', 1) AS primeiro_nome,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_completo, ' ', -1) AS ultimo_sobrenome,
    TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(nome_completo,'',primeiro_nome),'',ultimo_sobrenome)) AS nomes_do_meio
FROM `nomes`
```

**Referências**

> [TRIM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_trim.asp)
>
> [REPLACE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp)

Comment: Os novos campos que criei não posso usar no SQL, tipo primeiro_nome, se pudesse fazer isso, seria muito mais fácil de fazer o que preciso.